# Remove duplicate/unnecessary tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery, tags

I'm trying to build my own simple rich editor, so far so good.

I want to clean up my code somehow by removing unnecessary tags.

I want to transform:

```
<div id="text"><b><b><b>This</b> is </b>a messy</b> code</div>
```

Into:

```
<div id="text"><b>This is a messy</b> code</div>
```

The same goes for other tags like `<i>`, `<u>` etc.

Comment: Those tags are not necessarily unnecessary. I could define a CSS rule that applies to `b b`, and makes it red, for instance.

Comment: But they are usually unnecessary if they are generated automatically by the text editor he's making. Which by the way should be made in a way to not allow this sort of things to happen??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('b').find('b').unwrap();
$('i').find('i').unwrap();
$('u').find('u').unwrap();
```

Or more concisely:

```
$('b b, u u, i i').unwrap();
```

Comment: Great use of `.unwrap()` new to me. +1.

Comment: Hmm, its probably just me being a rookie, but if I paste $('b').find('b').unwrap(); in to my code, it doesnt work anymore. Is there something I've missed with your example?

Comment: @zvinx: You need to use it in the scope of your div tag. `$('#text').find('b b, u u, i i').unwrap();`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use jquery for this.  Instead, i'd use a server side tool to clean it up, which will depend on the platform and technology you're using server side.

One example would be [Html Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)

Comment: @RikudoSennin - of course it's an option.  You just cleanup the code when it's posted, not when it's being written.  It's stupid to try to do this as you type because you can't know what the user is trying to do until he's done.

Comment: I googled "jquery html tidy" and found this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/

Comment: Yes, that's one way of doing it, though many editors have the ability to present the HTML to the user, also, JavaScript is much better suited to edit DOM and HTML code then server side languages like PHP.

Comment: I've also been around http://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/
Check out the demo: http://www.antix.co.uk/Content/Demos/jQuery-htmlClean/Test.htm
Try pasting my example.. it doesnt remove the unnecessary tags :(